# Getting a 404 error when i use htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, oop, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem, i use htaccess to rewrite my url. It works half.. 
I use in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ index.php?page=admin [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ index.php?page=admin [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/?([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^admin/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^admin/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^admin/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1&action=$2&mode=$3 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^admin/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1&action=$2&mode=$3 [NC,L]
```

This works:

```
http://example.com/admin/editArticle/
```

But when i do this i got a 404 not found..

```
http://example.com/admin/editArticle/editMode/22
```

The controller has the following:

```
    if ($_GET['page'] == 'admin' && $_GET['subpage'] == 'editArticle' && $_GET['action'] == 'editMode' && !empty($_GET['mode'])) {
        echo 'Edit mode LOADED!';
        die();
        //$this->_model->setTemplate('articleEditMode');
    } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 'admin' && !empty($_GET['subpage'])) {
            $this->_model->setTemplate($_GET['subpage']);
        }
```

This is the button that i push to get to the page:

```
<a href="'.BASE_URL.'/admin/editArticle/editMode/'.$row['id'].'/">Edit article</a>
```

What do i wrong to get the error there?
Even if i do a var_dump in the index. I cannot reach it. I get always a 404..

Comment: you're not matching numbers anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ index.php?page=admin [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=admin&subpage=$1&action=$2&mode=$3 [NC,L]
```

No need to add one with `/$` and one without. You can use `/?$`.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, i did not know that but it does not solve the problem. I still cannot use the action variable